# C# Linq list with list in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I have a List containing a string property and another List.
How can I in a datagrid display both the string property AND the properties from the containing List?

```
public class Main
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Info> Info { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string Info1 { get; set; }
    public string Info2 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like my datagrid to show something like this:

```
 #Name    #Info1    #Info2
  name     info1     info2
  name     info1     info2
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What `DataGrid`? How do you want to show a single `Info1` and `Info2` for a `List<Info>`?

Comment: By just taking the last records from the Info List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take the last record from the Info list for each Main item you can write:

```
var q = from m in mainList
        let i = m.Info.LastOrDefault()
        select new
        {
            m.Name,
            Info1 = i == null ? null : i.Info1,
            Info2 = i == null ? null : i.Info2,
        };
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The static way if you can change the `Main` class is to provide `string`-properties of the properties in the other class that you want to expose:

```
public class Main
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Info> Info { get; set; }
    public string Info1 { 
        get {
            return Info == null || Info.Count == 0 ? "" 
                : Info.Last().Info1; 
        } 
    }
    public string Info2
    {
        get
        {
            return Info == null || Info.Count == 0 ? ""
                : Info.Last().Info2;
        }
    }
}
```

Other approaches:

- you could use a new class just for this requirement
- you could use an anonymous type:

  ```
  this.dataGridView1.DataSource = mains
  .Select(m => new { 
      m.Name, 
      Info1 = m.Info.Last().Info1,
      Info2 = m.Info.Last().Info2, // add null or count=0 check here
  }).ToList();
  ```